# If $\sigma$-algebra of product space is product of $\sigma$-algebras then at least one of the algebras is trivial

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I want to show that if $(X, \mathcal{A}),(Y, \mathcal{B})$ are measurable spaces and
$$
\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B} = \{ A\times B : A \in\mathcal{A}, B\in\mathcal{B} \}
$$
then $\mathcal{A} =\{\emptyset, X\}$ or $\mathcal{B} = \{\emptyset, Y\}$.

Comment: @GhostAmarth could you elaborate on why you think I'm missing conditions?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. You don‘t use $\mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B = \{A \times B : A \in\mathcal A , B\in\mathcal B\}$ as a (wrong) definition for the product $\sigma$-algebra but as a condition, right? If so, my bad.

Comment: @GhostAmarth That's right, I see how the wording of the question could be misleading, I'll try to rephrase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use contra position and to find a set in $\mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B$ which is not "rectangular", i.e. not of the form $A\times B$ for $A\in\mathcal A, B\in\mathcal B$.

Suppose $\{\emptyset, N, N^c, X\} \subseteq \mathcal A$ and $\{\emptyset, M, M^c, Y\} \subseteq \mathcal B$. Then
$$
K = (N\times M) \cup (N^c \times M^c) \in \mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B
$$
but
$$
K \notin \{A\times B : A \in\mathcal{A}, B\in\mathcal{B} \}.
$$